# Using For Loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Also my I need help with the loop to add more names when I put the number 2 instead of 1. Having issues with my code any help is appreciated. I know its simple For Loop coding, but I am stumped.

HTML

```
<p>Enter First Name: <input type="text" id="firstname">
 <span id="firstname_error"></span>
</p>
<p>Enter Last Name: <input type="text" id="lastname">
  <span id="lastname_error"></span>
</p>
<p>How Many Pets do you have?  (0-3):
  <input type="text" id="numpets" size="1" maxlength="1">
  <span id="numpets_error"></span>
</p>
<p>List your Pet's names:
    <input type="text" id="pet1">
    <input type="text" id="pet2">
    <input type="text" id="pet3">
</p>

<p><input id="mybutton" type="button" value="Submit Information"></p>

<p id="message"></p>
```

JavaScript

```
for(counter=1; counter<=numpets; counter++) {
  var PetId = "pet" + counter;
  var myPetName = document.getElementById(PetId).value;
  // Code to append test into a message variable
}
```

I have a total of three fields in the var "numpets", if I put the number 1 in that field, it will only the read the name in the number 1 field. If I put 2 it will only read the name in the number 2 field. I need it to be able to read all 3 three fields.

Comment: So what's not working?

Comment: Try starting the counter at 0

Comment: How can a question start with the word "also"? As with your loop, please start at the beginning. And please [edit] your question to show more details of how you try to use `myPetName`.

Comment: Where do you define `numpets`? There's nothing wrong with your for-loop. Try debugging the code in a browser's developer tools; watch the values of `counter`, `numpets`, and whether it's finding the elements.

Answer (score 1):

The for loop is ok. You have just to put your loop inside a function and call it with your button. And define the numpets like you did with the var namepet.